# Can't find ANY golden ratio in the schroder house...

Tags: fibonacci-numbers, golden-ratio

The Schroder House (The Netherlands) is supposed to be designed using the "golden ratio".
I'm having trouble finding these golden ratio's. A lot of rectangles, windows, house sections, etc. appear to be using the golden ratio, but, when measuring, I find that they actually don't.

Anyone who can point me to a few golden ratio's in the house? I even tried a pixel ruler for the measurements, but even then I find 70-30 or 65-35 ratio's, not "golden ratio's".

Plans and front wing of the building can be found [here](ftp://pc30.architettura.unirc.it/Urso/ABILITA'%20INFORMATICHE%2014_15/Materiali%20corso/Case%20unifamiliari/Architetture%20unifamiliari/Casa%20Schroeder%203.pdf).

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have any reference for the claim in the first sentence? Who is saying that?

Comment: http://modernistsummer.com/2010/09/01/the-rietveld-schroder/

Comment: https://books.google.be/books?id=2Etic6zQnyYC&pg=PA9&lpg=PA9&dq=golden+ratio+schroder+house&source=bl&ots=tebuevYxGr&sig=W1RfZkm3NcGbDEtK2kIaJIOFSrQ&hl=nl&sa=X&ei=QVwNVZ2WD5HyauvzgOAH&ved=0CCoQ6AEwBA

Comment: The Rietveld-Schröeder House and the Fifth Element Tomás García-Salgado The paper shows the positions of many golden rectangles (1.618)